# Buscar nombre en un fichero txt JAVA

Tags: java

mi problema es que creo un programa en el que el usuario tiene que introducir los datos de tres personas en un fichero txt, para que luego en un menu puedas consultar los datos de una persona en particular. El problema es que aunque cree el nombre "Belen", el programa no me lo encuentra en el fichero txt y me pasa directamente a la parte de que no existe. ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Contenido del fichero:

```
David Acedo España Madrid 26 
//////////////////////////////////////////////
Laura Gorrozarri España Madrid 26 
//////////////////////////////////////////////
Baxter Bay Americano Madrid 12
```

Código:

```
                        do {
                            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fichero.txt"));
                            System.out.println("Introduzca un nombre que quieras buscar: ");
                            nombre= entrada.next();

                            
                            boolean encontrado = false;
                            
                            while ((lineaTexto= br.readLine())!=null) {

                                if(lineaTexto.equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
                                    System.out.println(lineaTexto);

                                    for(int n=0;n<2;n++) {
                                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                                    }   
                                    encontrado = true;
                                    break;

                                }

                            }

                            if(!encontrado) System.out.println("El nombre no existe");

                                System.out.println("¿Quieres introducir otro nombre?");
                                respuesta=entrada.next();


                                br.close();
                        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("si"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        System.out.println("Error");
                    } ´´´
```

Comment: ya intentaste ponerle un `lineaTexto.trim()`?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pega el contenido de "fichero.txt"

Comment: Editada, ya he añadido el contenido del fichero

Comment: Vas a imprimir toda la línea? Me refiero a que si buscas David, va a imprimir esto: David Acedo España Madrid 26, así?

Comment: Efectivamente Rodrigo, es lo que busco

Answer (score 2):

Debido a que el código falta el inicio de algunas variables pero asumo que las llamas antes del `do while`, genera un poco de lio. Entiendo que usas `BufferedReader` como el lector del fichero y poder leerlo, pero después usas `Scanner` como lector de entrada. Puedes usar ambos para realizar ambas tareas y de paso te ahorras un par de líneas, como prefieras. El `while` dentro del `do while` es el que más me cuesta entender, en caso necesites que sea estrictamente con esa forma puedes comentarlo y edito esta pregunta, pero por tirar a algo más sencillo creo que te serviría de esta manera.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File fd = new File("tuFichero.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(fd);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (file.hasNext()) {
            list.add(file.nextLine());
        }
        file.close();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Indica que deseas buscar");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.contains(nombre)) {
                result.add(s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

El Scanner se encarga de lector de fichero y de entrada.  Se crea un `ArrayList` y mientras recorro el fichero saco cada línea que tenga. Puedes añadir un `Collections.sort` para ordenar pero no lo veo muy necesario.

De ahí pides el dato que se usará como búsqueda y se recorre la lista buscando resultados, los cuales por si acaso hay mas de uno se dirige a otra lista tan solo para mostrar cualquier coincidencia que encuentre.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.